# trace expensive part of code in spark ui back to part of pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-ui

I have some pyspark code with a very large number of joins and aggregation.  I've enabled spark ui and I've been digging in to the event timeling, job stages, and dag visualization.  I can find the task id and executor id for the expensive parts.  Does anyone have a tip how I can tie the expensive parts from the spark ui output (task id, executor id) back to parts of my pyspark code?  Like I can tell from the output that the expensive parts are caused by a large amount of shuffle operations from all my joins, but it would be really handy to identify which join was the main culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Your best approach is to start applying actions to your dataframes in various parts of the code. Pick a place, write it to a file, read it back, and continue.
This will allow you to identify your bottlenecks. As you can observe small portions of the executions in the UI as well.

Comment: thanks for the tip.  do you know what I would see on the event timeline, completed stages, or DAG visualization, that would tip me off that it was the "write" step?  and if I add more than one is there a way to distinguish them in the spark ui?